Why does Flink Table with Kafka Connector not return results for window-based aggregation operations?
I created a table with
    create table Bid(    
        auction  BIGINT,
        bidder  BIGINT,
        price  BIGINT,
        channel  VARCHAR,
        url  VARCHAR,
        dateTime  TIMESTAMP(3),
        extra  VARCHAR,
         `record_time` TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3) METADATA FROM 'tenter image description hereimestamp' ,  
        WATERMARK FOR dateTime AS dateTime - INTERVAL '4' SECOND)
  with (    'connector' = 'kafka',
    'topic' = 'test',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',
    'properties.group.id' = 'testGroup',
    'scan.startup.mode' = 'latest-offset',
    'format' = 'csv');

and when I run
 SELECT window_start, window_end, COUNT(*)

 FROM TABLE(

     TUMBLE(TABLE Bid, DESCRIPTOR(dateTime), INTERVAL '1' SECOND))

 GROUP BY window_start, window_end;

no matter how long I run the data generator, no result is returned.
but I'm sure there's data falls in the window, as I can get results from
select `record_time`,window_start, window_end
FROM TABLE(TUMBLE(TABLE Bid, DESCRIPTOR(dateTime), INTERVAL '1' SECOND));

the result is
results
I checked the Flink web monitor and I can see there are records received
enter image description here
enter image description here

try run this SELECT window_start, max(window_end) window_end, COUNT(*) FROM TABLE(TUMBLE(TABLE Bid, DESCRIPTOR(dateTime), INTERVAL '1' SECOND)) GROUP BY window_start;
or make sure dateTime is increasing, then you will have the expected result.

thank you very much, @jinzuchi! I tried your statement and it worked! Could you please explain a little bit why my original statement didn't work? Big thanks!

your statement still can work if the dateTime of the new message is earlier than the last one, when you group both window_start and window_end, kafka message is handled by org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.source.WatermarkToDataOutput#emitWatermark, required Timestamp earlier than before, or message will be dropped.
when group window_start only, data handle by org.apache.flink.table.runtime.operators.window.WindowTableFunctionOperator, it accept all data.
